# Integrating html code into existing Drupal 6 webform

Tags: webforms

I was provided some custom html code by my client’s email provider in order to automate getting the submissions into the client’s email system instead of the client having to enter them manually.  The code provided looks like this:

```
    <form method='get' accept-charset='UTF-8' name='oi_form' action='http://suivi.lnk01.com/xyz'>
    Email: <input type='text' name='email'/><br />
    First Name: <input type='text' name='firstname' /><br />
    Last Name: <input type='text' name='lastname' /><br />
    <input type='hidden' name='Source' value='Newsletter Website' /><br />
    <input type='hidden' name='goto' value='' />
    <input type='hidden' name='iehack' value='&#9760;' />
    <input type='submit' value='Subscribe' />
    </form>
```

I originally tried adding components (one for the first line and another for the 3 input lines after the fields) to the existing webform but it would not create a submission.

I then installed the webform remote post module, entered the target url value for the form, entered some data on the form, and submitted.  It created a submission but on the client’s side, the first name, last name, and source fields are all blank.  Has anyone had this same experience before ??

Answer (score 0):

The submission made might be reaching client's side as POST variables, can you try to alter your form's submission method to "GET" instead of "POST".

From

```
$form['#method'] = 'post';
```

to

```
$form['#method'] = 'get';
```

Comment: Finally getting back to this.  The last thing I had tried was modifying the value of $method in the webform remote post module from post to get but this still didn't change the results on the client's end.  The input fields appear to be getting built fine right before drupal_http_request is called so I'm thinking it is an issue on their end but I’m still troubleshooting.